# What does the MySQL reconnect flag value mean?

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I have code that looks much like this, only with error handling (which doesn't get triggered). It's called in a multithreaded app (once per thread that need a connection), using MySQL 5.5.37-0 on Ubuntu 13.10.1:

```
DBConnection = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_options((MYSQL *) DBConnection, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");
mysql_real_connect(DBConnection, ...);
my_bool reconnect = true;
mysql_options(DBConnection, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
mysql_query(DBConnection, "SET wait_timeout=60"); //!!!
printf("reconnect flag %d", DBConnection->reconnect);
```

I've cut the disconnect timeout way down so I can test the reconnection code (1 minute rather than the default 8 hours). edit: and I'm setting _RECONNECT option after real_connect per [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html) because it works more reliably for me.

In mysql.h the relevant code says:

```
my_bool reconnect;  /* set to 1 if automatic reconnect */
```

The value of that "reconnect" field appears to be random. Grabbing values from the log above I see: 100, 104, 106, 108, 108, 38, 43, 56, 59, 63, 64, 88, 92, 98

This doesn't appear to be documented, [the relevant page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-data-structures.html) just says:

> **MYSQL**
>   This structure represents a handle to one database connection.
>   It is used for almost all MySQL functions. Do not try to make 
>   a copy of a MYSQL structure. There is no guarantee that such 
>   a copy will be usable.

A ["lost connection" help page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) says:

> Prior to MySQL 5.0.19, even if the reconnect flag in the MYSQL structure is equal to 1,

I don't think I've ever seen it actually set to 1, regardless of whether I use the mysql_options() call above to set it. Does anyone know what this means, and whether there's any significance to the actual value?

I've been chasing slightly odd behaviour after reconnects for a while and I wonder if this might have something to do with it (sometimes auto-reconnect fails but manually disconnecting and reconnecting works).

---

I've swapped the order and used mysql_options rather than SQL with no visible change to the "never 0 or 1" result. New code:

```
DBConnection = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_options((MYSQL *) DBConnection, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");
my_bool reconnect = true;
mysql_options(DBConnection, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
mysql_options(DBConnection, MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "60");
mysql_real_connect(DBConnection, ...);
printf("reconnect flag %d", DBConnection->reconnect);
```

Same result, but it seems your exact values will vary (my comment below used a different run and got different values). Starting up my code with 30 threads I got: 101, 101, 101, 106, 109, 112, 112, 115, 117, 118, 120, 123, 47, 56, 56, 59, 62, 68, 80, 81, 81, 88, 88, 88, 90, 91, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96 (the easy way to get these out of the log file involves sorting it, so the ordering is not what was there originally). Main thing is that it's not "1" as the manual says it should be. And bit 0 is not always set.

Comment: FWIW MariaDB always returns 1 or 0, and we've switched to that for other reasons.

Comment: 2018 that value is no longer visible in the public interface. Apparently they didn't know what it meant either :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of MySQL, auto-reconnect behavior is slightly different; for instance, there is [--skip-reconnect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_reconnect) option also. [This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html) explains it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see anything on that page that describes the meaning of the reconnect flag values. Can you possibly expand your answer to quote the relevant parts?

Comment: Sorry @DigiTester, I did not carefully read your question. I also could not find how/why the random values you noticed get assigned; however since `reconnect` is used as a boolean, all non-zero values evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: What version are you using, by the way?

Comment: sorry, should have included that: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1. I know that the boolean works, and my code seems to work, I'm just hunting for the reasons _why_ it acts as it does (and perhaps solve the underlying issue)

Comment: Try setting the timeout also using `mysql_options` instead of the quer; so, something like, `mysql_options(DBConnection, MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "60")`. Also, `mysql_real_connect()` should be called **after** all your `mysql_options()` calls.

Comment: See edit. But I just fired up 30 threads with mysql_options calls all before the real_connect and same result: 101, 101, 102, 106, 115, 119, 121, 121, 37, 40, 44, 46, 48, 56, 57, 59, 60, 63, 66, 70, 73, 73, 76, 86, 86, 89, 90, 91, 93, 96, 97

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the server, call mysql_init() to initialize a connection handler, then call "mysql_real_connect()"" with that handler (with other information like the host name, user name, and password). Upon connection, mysql_real_connect() sets the reconnect flag to a value of 1 in versions of the API older than 5.0.3, or 0 in newer versions. A value of 1 for this flag indicates that if a statement cannot be performed because of a lost connection, to try reconnecting to the server before giving up.

Comment: My question specifically says that I have not seen either 0 or 1 as reconnect flag values. It also links to the manual page that you are quoting, and the code sample given includes the calls that you suggest.

Comment: can you elaborate your question so that i can answer with your way?